# How to get powershell to read a SQL Server error log

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need your help with PowerShell today. I have a SQL Server instance (on a server named `VMDEV-APP11`) configured as a Central Management Server (CMS) in which I have registered all my Dev/Test/Prod SQL instances and I want to use PowerShell to read the SQL Server error logs from all my servers. I have a query which retrieves all my SQL Server instances but when I pipe the output of this into a call to `ReadErrorLog`, I get an error.

This is the code that retrieves my list of the SQL Server instances which are registered on my CMS (note that I exclude my SQL Server 2000 instances):

```
Set-Location D:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\CMS
# Define functions to query SQL Server and write data to a SQL table
. ./invoke-sqlcmd2.ps1
. ./write-datatable.ps1

Invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "VMDEV-APP11" -Database dba -Query "select s.server_name from msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers s, msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups g where s.server_group_id = g.server_group_id and g.name not like '2000%'" 

server_name
-----------
INF-SRV14
VMDEV-APP15
NEX-SRV48
...
```

And this is what I thought would work and the error I actually get:

```
Invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "VMDEV-APP11" -Database dba -Query "select s.server_name from msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers s, msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups g where s.server_group_id = g.server_group_id and g.name not like '2000%'" | foreach-object { $_.server_name.ReadErrorLog() }
```

Error:

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ReadErrorLog'.
>   At D:\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\CMS\db_errorlog.ps1:38 char:284
>   + ... reach-object { $_.server_name.ReadErrorLog() }
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

I suspect I need to convert the string returned by my query to another type of object (a server name perhaps?) in order to get the `ReadErrorLog()` call to work but I don't know how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ken

Comment: Where did you get the .ReadErrorLog() method from?

Comment: I was trying to use ReadErrorLog() based on this site:   http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/22/use-powershell-to-parse-sql-server-2012-error-logs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to invoke the `ReadErrorLog()` method on a `DataRow` column value, which is a string.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking

Invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "VMDEV-APP11" -Database dba -Query "select s.server_name from msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers s, msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_server_groups g where s.server_group_id = g.server_group_id and g.name not like '2000%'" | `
foreach-object { 
    $server = $_.server_name 
    $logs = (get-item SQLSERVER:\sql\$server\default).ReadErrorLog()
    # $logs is a DataTable so you can iterate the rows however you wish
}
```

This assuming all your servers are default instances, otherwise you may need to fiddle around a bit more to target specific instances.

Comment: Thanks Kev.  Unfortunately I do have some named instances.  I tried the following code:  `Invoke-sqlcmd2 <query_SQL_instances>  | `
`foreach-object {  If ($_.server_name -like "*\*")  {$server = $_.server_name} Else   {$server = $_.server_name + "\default"}    $server = $_.server_name $logs = (get-item SQLSERVER:\sql\$server).ReadErrorLog()  }`   This works for the named instance but not the default instance.  Any suggestions on what's wrong?

Comment: D'oh:  I just saw my mistake in the previous comment.  There's an extra `$server = $_.server_name` that should have been removed.  I'm good now.

Comment: @Ken - cool, glad that helped. If answers are helpful then you can mark as correct and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The code I'm running on my SQL Central Management server is:

```
$logs = 0..6 | % { (get-item SQLSERVER:\sql\<servername>\default).ReadErrorLog($_) }
```

Originally, I got this to work by adding the service account that ran the PowerShell code to the local **Administrators** Windows group *AND* creating a SQL login with **sysadmin** privileges on the remote SQL server host.  Not sursprisingly, my security officer had an issue with this.  My initial attempts to reduce access resulted i the following error:

```
WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect 
 to WMI on 'NEX-SRV1' failed with the following error: SQL Server WMI provider
is not available on NEX-SRV1. --> Invalid namespace
```

After quite a bit of fooling around, I have what I think is the minimum security needed to read the SQL error logs.  Perform the following grants on the remote server running the SQL Server database:

**Local Windows Group**

- Add the service account to the "Distributed COM Users" group

**WMIMgmt.msc**

Add the service account to each of the following branches with all security options EXCEPT "Edit Security"

- Root > cimv2
- Root > cimv2 > ms_409
- Root > Microsoft > SQLServer > ComputerManagement

**SQL Server**

- Create a SQL login for the service account and add it to the "Security Admin" role.

After I had made these changes, I have the ability to monitor SQL Error logs from a central location without having to grant crazy levels of access to the service account.